# Ways to freeze/Pause Shield UI Chart showing forex data flow?

Tags: javascript, shieldui

I am using Shield UI JavaScript Charts to visualize forex data. The charts are being constantly populated with data which is displayed over even intervals of time. However I need to be able to turn off/freeze some of them. The charts themselves have no such functionality, so am looking for some ideas/solutions I can use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible scenarios I can think of.

The first one is just to pause the data visualization so that once resumed, the chart having been hidden will have the same points as the others.In order to do so, you may use a checkbox and recreate the chart only if the checkbox is checked/unchecked.

The second scenario involves skipping those data values that have been displayed on the other charts. In order to do so you only need to place the data binding inside the checkbox checked/unchecked clause.Once resumed, the chart having been paused will contain less points compared to the other non-paused charts on your page.